# Region folding in my Visual Studio Code is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've been making **C# scripts** using **Visual Studio Code** for my game development. I noticed when I was organizing my codes, ****#region** & **#endregion** folding** does not work. It seems to work more as a *comment* than a *region*. Is there a way to enable region folding in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "does not work"?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with C++?

Comment: It just seems to work more as a comment than a #region @cigien

Comment: Please add that information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @NathanPierson I'm sorry I'm new to programming. I just thought c# and c++ are the same.

Comment: I'm having this issue with Jinja2 files. The issue is that these _used_ to work within `<!-- #region Name -->` and after a recent VS Code update they no longer do. Now, commenting on Jinja2 moved to `{# ... #}` but even with this new syntax they just don't fold. All other languages I'm using (CSS, Python, JavaScript, HTML, Vue...) work as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You'll need an extension for this.**

For example, *"[#region folding for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder)"* by maptz.

Visual Studio proper has it built in, but VS Code is more like an editor than an IDE.

There was originally [some discussion about adding this to the program](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105), but ultimately [the developers decided](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3422) just to do enough that extensions (like that linked above) could provide the functionality.

Comment: vscode has supported it natively but we still lack of a region viewer

Answer (score 5):

You can enable this without an extension by changing the `foldingStrategy` setting (File > Preferences > Settings) to `indentation`

[image: Setting]

Then add `//region - "description"` to begin a region and `//endregion` to end one.

The comment syntax (//) may differ according to the programming language you use.

[image: Expanded]

[image: Collapsed]

`Works on Visual Studio Code Version 1.75.1`

Found this setting thanks to this Github comment: [micharaze commented on Feb 22, 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91140#issuecomment-589922208)

Comment: This works fine without any need for extension! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for sharing its working in my end.