# #region stopped working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm programming with Python on VSCode and have been using `#region` `#endregion` for a while to organize everything and fold the parts I'm not currently working with.

Today when I opened VSCode, the fold symbol `>` didn't show at the regions, only at the functions, loops and other functional code parts.

Is there a way that I may accidentally have turned off the region folding behavior? How do I turn it back on? I tryed reopening the file, the program, running it, adding new regions...

VSCode info:
Version: 1.63.2 (user setup)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:53:24.645Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT ia32 10.0.19042

---

After a couple of days working with the code without folding, it suddenly fixed itself out of nowhere.

If anyone would try a guess as to what happened and how to prevent it from happening again, that'd still be great.

---

By the time I finished editing this post and Alt+tabbed back to VSCode, it was broken again... so please help haha!

Comment: I've the same problem. Please, can someone help us pls ?
My vscode version is
Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:39:46.686Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.11.0-46-generic

Comment: I had the same problem, so I've installed the extension which is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64773871/1829670

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to indentation? It seems that for --#Region to work, everything between the --#Region and --#EndRegion has to be indented.

I don't know if this was always the case - I didn't think it was, but I've just opened up VS Code and found that it will now only fold regions if everything between the tags is indented.